# Damaged RAW Files

Tags: lightroom-6

I use a Nikon d750, shooting in both RAW and JPEG. My pictures look fine on my camera lcd screedn, but when I download to my computer, about 5 to 10% of my files are damaged. I have used both Adobe Lightroom and Branch to download pictures. For example, a photo that looks fine in Branch is damaged when I call it up in Adobe Camera RAW or Photoshop to edit it. How can I fix damaged files? How can I prevent the damage in the first place?

Comment: Are 5-10% of both the raw and jpeg files (of the same image) corrupted? Or only one or the other? When you look at a raw file in Branch, you're most likely only seeing the jpeg preview attached to the raw file. When you open them to edit in Adobe (PS and LR both use ACR under the hood to render raw image data), the actual raw data is being processed to provide the image on your screen.

Comment: Are all the problem images on the same card?

Comment: Two different sd cards. Both brand new, labeled as 260 mbps write speed and 299 mbps read speed. Different images are corrupted, but both cards (RAW slot 1 and JPEG slot 2) contain corrupted images. Nikon told me to try their free program Nikon Transfer2. I got even more bad images.

Answer (score 2):

**Rule #1 - as soon as an SD card starts to play up, bin it.**

You could try PhotoRec to recover the damaged files, but discard the SD card afterwards.
I used to get through literally thousands of SD cards a year for work. As soon as they start to misbehave, discard them. they are not worth fighting once they start to fail.

Sure, you can reformat round the damaged sectors; until next time, then next time, until eventually one will firmware lock right in the middle of something important & you're locked out.

Comment: As I noted above, I started getting bad files with 2 Sandisk sd cards. Both were purchased quite recently, but they were labeled as 90 mbps read speed (no write speed listed). So I replaced them with the 2 brand new sd cards I described above. My images were corrupt on both cards on their first batch of photos.

Comment: If you'd given us an accurate description of the issue in the first place neither of us would have wasted our time.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

- Reimport in a different way cable instead of a card reader (or vice versa). Also try wireless if your camera has it.
- Open them in different RAW processing software.  (e.g. darktable or RawTherapee)

Comment: I just opened the files in Windows 10 without going through Adobe Branch or Lightroom or Nikon Transfer 2. I opened them on both my desktop and laptop. The files were all fine on both computers, although the desktop display was darker than the laptop. That seems to point to the Adobe editing software as the problem.

Comment: I would keep trying different programs until you find one that works, but stick with those that actually read the raw image data.  @Michael C's idea that you may be seeing the embedded jpg preview rather than the raw data may very well apply in whatever default photo viewer Windows 10 has as well.